# Angularjs checkbox checked by default on load and disables Select list when checked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, selectlist

noob on stack overflow here. I am working on a webpage that has a transfer job function. This lets the user check a check-box to send the job back to the office, or select a technician from a list of all that are available. My question is how to setup the check-box so that it is checked by default when the page loads and have the select list disabled accordingly. Here is the code that I have for it at the moment:

```
<div ng-app="">
  Send to Office: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-checked="true"><br/>
  <select id="transferTo" ng-disabled="checked">
    <option>Tech1</option>
    <option>Tech2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and here is a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/hugmungus/LvHJw/5/

Currently, the page loads with the check-box checked, but the list is not disabled. If you un-check then re-check the it, the list becomes disabled.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you use ng-model, you don't want to also use ng-checked.  Instead just initialize the model variable to true.  **Normally you would do this in a controller that is managing your page (add one).**  In your fiddle I just did the initialization in an ng-init attribute for demonstration purposes.

http://jsfiddle.net/UTULc/

```
<div ng-app="">
  Send to Office: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true"><br/>
  <select id="transferTo" ng-disabled="checked">
    <option>Tech1</option>
    <option>Tech2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked exactly as I had hoped. Thanks especially for the quick reply and explaining how to correct the issue.

Comment: It is not working foe me, I tried also same way: div class = "columns float-left" ng-click="inventory.openColumnSelector();">
                <img src="static/img/icons/icon_columns@1x.png">
            </div>
             <div class="columns-selection-box arrow-up" id="checkboxes" ng-show="inventory.showColumnSelector">
                    <input type="checkbox"  class = "checkbox" ng-model="inventory.status" ng-init="checked=true" />Status
                <br/></div>, on click I am showing the div and status field has to be checked...

Comment: @AnitaMehta Get rid of the ng-init in your template.  In your controller, set scope.inventory.status = true.

Comment: @KarlZilles setting to true instead of 1 worked for me - thanks!

Comment: You beauty @KarenZilles!!! I couldn't even think `ng-init` can be used at element level.

Comment: @KishorPawar You shouldn't use ng-init in your html if you can help it, better to set the value in your controller.   I did it here just to make the example easy to read.

Comment: @KarenZilles What could be the problem in doing so?

Comment: @KishorPawar It's considered bad style.  There is no technical problem with it.  Up to you.

Comment: @KarenZilles okay. Actually I am creating checkboxes in ng-repeat. That's why I had to do it in html.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in the controller    ( controller as syntax below)

**controller:**

```
vm.question= {};
vm.question.active = true;
```

**form**

```
<input ng-model="vm.question.active" type="checkbox" id="active" name="active">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the directive, can achieve it by using the ng-init and ng-checked. below demo link shows how to set the initial value for checkbox in angularjs.

[demo link](https://plnkr.co/edit/SeX6G8EzS95i42V0Q2fI?p=preview):

```
<form>
    <div>
      Released<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Released" ng-bind-html="ACR.Released" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-init='Released=true' ng-checked='true' /> 
      Inactivated<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Inactivated" ng-bind-html="Inactivated" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-init='Inactivated=false' ng-checked='false' /> 
      Title Changed<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Title" ng-bind-html="Title" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-init='Title=false' ng-checked='false' />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>Released value is  <b>{{Released}}</b></div>
    <br/>
    <div>Inactivated  value is  <b>{{Inactivated}}</b></div>
    <br/>
    <div>Title  value is  <b>{{Title}}</b></div>
    <br/>
  </form>

// Code goes here

  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

         });
```