# Default Select all checkboxes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a app in angularjs. I have problem while showing all checkbox selected when page open.

here is my code:

```
<div class="check_box">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAllStatus" ng-click="checkAllTypes()">
<label for="checkbox1"><span for="checkbox1">All</span></label>
</div>
</li>

<li ng-repeat="customersFlowsList in customersFlows | unique:'type'" ng-init="checkAllTypes()">

<div class="check_box">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox"  ng-model="filter[customersFlowsList.type]">
<label for="checkbox1"><span for="checkbox1">{{customersFlowsList.type | customerType}}</span></label>
</div>
</li>
```

Here is my js code:

```
$scope.checkAllStatus = function()
    {
       console.log($scope.selectedAll)
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.customersFlows, function (customersFlowsList) {
           $scope.filterLink[customersFlowsList.linkStatus] = $scope.selectedAll;
        });

    }
```

On click of button all checkboxes selected(this is working),but I want when page is open then all checkboxes should be selected.

Comment: simulate a click on page open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs checkbox checked by default on load and disables Select list when checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374146/angularjs-checkbox-checked-by-default-on-load-and-disables-select-list-when-chec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in controller before template load

```
 $scope.checkAllStatus = function() {
   console.log($scope.selectedAll)
   if ($scope.selectedAll) {
     $scope.selectedAll = true;
   } else {
     $scope.selectedAll = false;
   }
   angular.forEach($scope.customersFlows, function(customersFlowsList)         {
     $scope.filterLink[customersFlowsList.linkStatus] = $scope.selectedAll;
   });

 }


  $scope.selectedAllStatus = true;
  $scope.checkAllStatus()
```