# Why this ng-model variable is empty on load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i use this code to render checkbox list

```
<label ng-repeat="service in user.service_list">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    ng-model="selectedServices[service.id]"
    value="{{service.name}}"
    ng-checked="isChecked(service.id)"
  > {{service.name}}
</label>
```

but when page is loaded selectedServices variable is empty, but values are checked. Only if i refill checkbox list selectedServices value will filled too. How to fill value without recheck?

Comment: Is `selectedServices` initialized as an empty array or object in your `$scope`?

Comment: yes it is.     angular.extend($scope, {
        user : {},
  selectedServices : [],

Comment: Do not use `ng-model` and `ng-checked` at the same time. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17374273/7661119

Comment: Yea, this resolved my problem!